# ksqlDB CLI not working with a dockerized ksqlDB Server

Tags: docker, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm trying to connect a ksqlDB CLI (running on a container using image [0.20.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/ksqldb-cli/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated)) but it says the [ksqlDB] Server Status is unknow...

```
    CLI v0.20.0, Server v<unknown> located at http://127.0.0.1:8088
    WARNING: Could not identify server version.
             Non-matching CLI and server versions may lead to unexpected errors.
    Server Status: <unknown>
```

... which is funny since I'm running the ksqlDB server (version 0.20.0 as well) based on [these](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/install-ksqldb-with-docker/#connect-ksqldb-cli-to-a-dockerized-ksqldb-server) instructions and I see the startup log

```
[2021-08-23 12:28:10,795] INFO ksqlDB API server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8088 (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication:389)
[2021-08-23 12:28:10,796] INFO Server up and running (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:93)
[2021-08-23 12:28:11,923] INFO Successfully submitted metrics to Confluent via secure endpoint (io.confluent.support.metrics.submitters.ConfluentSubmitter:146)
```

Also, in Docker Desktop (I'm running this on a Windows) I see it under the Container/Apps tab as running on port 8088 and it allows me to "Open in browser" where I see the response

```
KsqlServerInfo  
version "0.20.0"
kafkaClusterId  "lkc-****"
ksqlServiceId   "default_"
serverStatus    "RUNNING"
```

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: There was some issue that is fixed via https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/7932 -- not sure if you might hit it?

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax but I don't think this is related since I'm running the latest image published by Confluent (~8 days ago)

Comment: Not sure. In doubt please file a ticket: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue to be that the server definition in the `docker-compose.yml` had to match the name in the command.

Command:

```
docker exec -it ksqldb-cli ksql http://ksqldb-server:8088
```

Docker-compose:

```
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.4.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
```

Hope this helps from another point of view.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the container doesn't know how to reach an external server; it will try to connect to itself on `127.0.0.1`

You would need to follow some steps like the following

```
# create a network
docker network create ksql-network

# TODO start Zookeeper and Kafka 

# start the server on that network
docker run -d --name=ksql-server --network=ksql-network ... confluentinc/ksql-server:<version>

# Start the CLI to point at the '--name' on the '--network'    
docker run --network=ksql-network confluentinc/ksql-cli:<version> http://ksql-server:8088
```

Or, you should just [use Compose](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/installing/)